# correlated errors and regression

Tags: regression, standard-error

When a linear regression model yields correlated errors it is claimed that the standard error of the estimators is under estimated. Can anyone give a proof of this fact? This is stated on page 94 of Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani

Comment: Check this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114564/why-autocorrelation-affects-ols-coefficient-standard-errors

Comment: A proof is impossible because the statement is false.  When the errors are strongly *negatively* correlated, then the standard error of the estimators will be overestimated.  Refer back to your source of the claim to check what additional assumptions or qualifications it is making--and please let us know what this source is.