# VIF and coefficient variance-covariance matrix for OLS

Tags: least-squares, covariance-matrix, variance-inflation-factor

After reading this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114564/why-autocorrelation-affects-ols-coefficient-standard-errors), I am not very clear on how to get to the formula of VIF ($1/1-R^2$) as part of the variances on the diagonals of the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients, if auto correlation exists.

How is the VIF formula derived? Thanks.